# Customizing name of "Query Results" tab

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'd like to customize the name of each *Query Result* tab to something other than that default name.

I use to execute multiple queires, but each time the the output displayed as QUERY RESULT 1, QUERY RESULT 2 .... so on. Its difficult to identify and verify the matching SQL Query.

so i want to set the QUERY RESULT tab name, so that it displays(Output) the customized name instead of Default Name. E.g (setting to Table_name, search names, key words to identify the parent query triggered) etc.,

Answer (score 2):

You cant rename these tabs via code/SQL, but you can use your mouse.

[image]

But you really shouldn't need to.

"Its difficult to identify and verify the matching SQL Query"

If you mouse over the tab, it shows you the SQL/code behind it. You can also click the SQL button to copy the code to the clipboard.

[image]

Comment: Would be great if before each select statement I could call 'set queryresultname NAME' similar to the way you can rename worksheets.

Comment: @Rubio Maybe what you want is a Report. Are you familiar with this feature? 10 minute video here -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AtQbENBCE0

Comment: @Jeff Reports are much better than what I had in mind. I remember taking a glance at reports long time ago but never really learned what you can do with them. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Rubio thanks for that - this is why I spend so much time here, the oppty to reach real users is amazing.